Better looping script in R
I have a working script that does the following:
It loops through a dataframe with taxon names, finding the corresponding numerical ID for each taxon name. If the ID is NA it keeps the name from the dataframe. It writes this into a new dataframe. It works, but I think its a little messy and I am looking for any suggestions to improve it or make it simpler. I am using the package taxize to get the IDs but the suggestions don't need to necessarily use it.
Here is the example data and script:



Kingdom
Phylum
Class
Order
Family
Genus




Bacteria
Firmicutes
Clostridia
Eubacteriales
Lachnospiraceae
Dorea


Bacteria
Firmicutes
Clostridia
Eubacteriales
Oscillospiraceae
GGB9634


Bacteria
Firmicutes
Clostridia
Eubacteriales
Clostridiaceae
Clostridiaceae_unclassified



structure(list(Kingdom = c("Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria"
), Phylum = c("Firmicutes", "Firmicutes", "Firmicutes"), Class = c("Clostridia", 
"Clostridia", "Clostridia"), Order = c("Eubacteriales", "Eubacteriales", 
"Eubacteriales"), Family = c("Lachnospiraceae", "Oscillospiraceae", 
"Clostridiaceae"), Genus = c("Dorea", "GGB9634", "Clostridiaceae_unclassified"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

script:
sad<-taxa[1:3,] # dataframe shown above
numID <- data.frame(sad$Kingdom) # dataframe to store the IDs
taxize::taxize_options(ncbi_sleep = 0.9) # adjust http request rate

for(r in 1:length(sad[,1])){
  for(c in 2:length(sad[1,])){
    sadID<-taxize::get_uid(sad[r,c], ask=F)[1]
    if(is.na(sadID)){
      numID[r,c]<- sad[r,c]
    }
    else{
      numID[r,c] <- sadID
    }
  }}
names(numID)<-names(sad)

#numID (wanted output)
structure(list(Kingdom = c("Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria"),
Phylum = c("Firmicutes", "Firmicutes", "Firmicutes"), 
Class = c("186801","186801", "186801"),
Order = c("186802", "186802", "186802"), 
Family = c("186803", "216572", "31979"), 
Genus = c("189330","GGB9634", "Clostridiaceae_unclassified")), row.names = c(NA,3L), class = "data.frame")


If I were to use this script
(or any other), but wanted to start with column 4 instead of 2, how could I do that?, since I am using c both for sad and numID.
The script is working but I want to improve it.

please share the data as code.You can use dput(sad). paste its output in the question.
Also, please provide an example of the output.

I haven’t got the package but something like the following should work: phyla <- unlist(sad[, -1L]); uids <- unlist(taxize::get_uid(phyla, ask = FALSE)). Then you just need to handle the NA values and assign the result back: numID <- sad; numID[, -1L] <- ifelse(is.na(uids), phyla, uids).

Some general comments: (1) instead of length(table[, 1]) you can use nrow(table) and equivalently ncol() for the columns. (2) The pattern 1 : some_length is error-prone, because it gives incorrect results for empty data (instead of an empty vector it returns 1 : 0!). So you should always use seq_len() instead: seq_len(nrow(sad)). And instead of seq_len(length(x)) you should use seq_along(x). (3) Although R defines abbreviations for TRUE and FALSE, it’s general consensus that these should never be used in scripts: they are less readable, and they can be overwritten.

get_uid takes vectors. You can simply do:
numID <- sad
numID[] <- lapply(
  sad, 
  \(x) dplyr::coalesce(taxize::get_uid(x, ask = FALSE) |> unclass(), x)
)

This passes each column to get_uid and writes the results to numID. unclass will drop the uid class and convert to character. coalesce will replace NA values with the original names. You could improve things by only requesting IDs for unique values.

  Kingdom     Phylum  Class  Order Family                       Genus
1       2 Firmicutes 186801 186802 186803                      189330
2       2 Firmicutes 186801 186802 216572                     GGB9634
3       2 Firmicutes 186801 186802  31979 Clostridiaceae_unclassified


